# Deleted firebase value still shows up in datasnaphot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm listing Firebase data in a recyclerView, and when I swipe a recyclerView item, its value is deleted from FireBase. As soon as it is deleted, I would like to add the updated values to an arrayList(minus the deleted value of course). My issue is that even after the value has been deleted, it still shows up in the updated snap shot. The code is below.

```
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        if(bidslist.get(position).getUsername().equals(userEmail)){
            deleteRef = bidslist.get(position).getMsgID();

            mRef.orderByChild("msgID").equalTo(deleteRef).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        deleteKey = childSnapshot.getKey();
                        mRef.child(deleteKey).removeValue();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }

            });

            if(bidslist.get(position).getAmount().equals(biggest.toString())){
                /*removing data from the second referance. As soon as this is done I would like to update 
                the reference with the new snapshot, excluding the deleted one.*/

                highestRef.child(fbid).removeValue();

               mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       /*This is supposed to be the new snapshot*/
                      BidFirebaseObject obj = dataSnapshot.getValue(BidFirebaseObject.class);
                       Log.d("dhat", obj.getAmount());
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                   }
               });

            }

            //remove it from the adapter
            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
                adapter.removeItem(position);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the data actually removed from the database when you check the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/)? Also: the `onCancelled` callbacks might get called and by ignoring them you may miss important messages. Simple implementation: `public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { throw firebaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Yes, the data is not there when I check the console. maybe let me check what happens in the onCancelled callback

Comment: No exceptions thrown

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the second `onDataChange` is giving you the 'updated' snapshot before the delete operation in the first `onDataChange` has actually completed?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify the adapter of any changes:

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

> void notifyDataSetChanged()
>   Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

more info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I'm not trying to update the recyclerview, I want to update an arrayList with the new dataSnapshot, but the deleted item is still appearing in the new datasnapshot.

Comment: @PamelaSillah if the data is getting remove in the first listener, and after that immediately you are retrieving the data, then maybe add a progress dialog with some seconds, since if the internet is slow then you will still get the data that is getting deleted in the second snapshot

Comment: @PamelaSillah, did the answer/comment help? If so please upvote and accept as correct, thank you!